# Problemas de conexión utilizando ConnectionString C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy realizando una conexión a la bd sql server 2014 utilizando connectionString, pero me sale el siguiente error. espero su apoyo.

este es mi App.config

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.2;Initial Catalog=BD_SGC_V2;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userdev;Password=-21-5254"

Comment: El error es porque no encuentra dbconexion en el .config, tienes mas de un proyecto????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con este connectionstring:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Negocios2017;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

[SQL Server Connection Strings for ASP.NET Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera a ver que tal este es con windows authentication

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="dbconexion" connectionString="data source=localhost; initial catalog=negocios2017;persist security info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```